# Generate testcategory based on vsmdi file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I'm upgrading a couple of big solutions from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2012. Now I want to delete the .vsmdi files for the unit tests. I want to use the new TestCategory attribute.

Is it possible to generate the test categories above the test methods bases on a list in the vsmdi file? So in example I have the lists "Shoppingcart" and "Nightly" and if the test is in that vsmdi list, the category is set above the method.

A simple find replace (multiple times per list?) is also a good solution. The problem is that we have a couple of thousand tests where one or multiple categories should be placed.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I just went through this.  Our VSMDI defined several lists and covered around 2500 tests.  Unfortunately I couldn't find a one-stop utility, but I did manage to get it done with a quick and dirty console app in combination with an existing test list migration tool: http://testlistmigration.codeplex.com/

This extension will produce Test Play Lists from the vsmdi, a smiple XML structure with full test names.  My utility reads the play list XML into a HeapSet, then iterates each test file in a directory, parses each method that begins with [TestMethod], checks whether it's referenced in the play list and if so adds the test category attribute.  It's ugly, but it works and I wrote it in about an hour.

Here is the C# code...and remember it was written hastily with no regard to aesthetic or best practice. It solved my problem and would otherwise be thrown away if not for this post :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using TestListMigration.Properties;

namespace TestListMigration
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HashSet<string> tests = new HashSet<string>();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(Settings.Default.Playlist);
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("Add");
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                tests.Add(node.Attributes["Test"].Value);
            }
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Settings.Default.TestPath);
            foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles("*.cs",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                var testFileReader =file.OpenText();
                string fileContent = testFileReader.ReadToEnd();
                testFileReader.Close();
                bool dirty = false;
                var namespaceMatch = Regex.Match(fileContent, @"namespace ([a-zA-Z\.]*)");
                if (namespaceMatch.Success){
                    string namespaceName = namespaceMatch.Groups[1].Value;
                    var classNameMatch = Regex.Match(fileContent, @"[\n\r\t ]*(public|internal|public sealed) class ([a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)");
                    if (classNameMatch.Success)
                    {
                        string className = classNameMatch.Groups[2].Value;
                        StringBuilder newFile = new StringBuilder();
                        StringReader reader = new StringReader(fileContent);
                        string line;
                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            newFile.AppendLine(line);
                            if (line.Contains("[TestMethod]") || line.Contains("[TestMethod()]"))
                            {
                                bool methodLineRead = false;
                                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                                while (!methodLineRead)
                                {
                                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                                    buffer.AppendLine(line);
                                    if (line.Contains("void")){
                                        methodLineRead=true;
                                        var testNameMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"[\n\r\t ]*public void ([a-zA-Z\._0-9]*)\(\)");
                                        if (testNameMatch.Success)
                                        {
                                            string fullName = namespaceName + "." + className + "." + testNameMatch.Groups[1].Value;
                                            if (tests.Contains(fullName) && !buffer.ToString().Contains("\t\t[TestCategory(Category." + Settings.Default.Category + ")]"))
                                            {
                                                newFile.AppendLine("\t\t[TestCategory(Category." + Settings.Default.Category + ")]");
                                                dirty = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                newFile.Append(buffer.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        if (dirty)
                        {
                            File.WriteAllText(file.FullName, newFile.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe someone could use your code one day. For now I used Search and Replace. Also powerfull trick ;-). Thanks for sharing